# How to Add objects without them hitting each other

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im doing a test/game and i have bumped in a problem I cant figure out.
I am trying  to add Objects (in my case Bricks) to the stage ,but adding in such a way that they never hit one other, and when there is`t any space left on the stage ,to stop adding them and to display lets say "no more space".

The stage is 500x500px and the "block" is 75px to 30px ,but I need this to be able to do the same with other objects with different width and height. 
I would be very thankful to an solution for this.:)

The creating of the blocks is done in an AS.
There is a movieClip exported for AS with the name Block

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class MainClass extends MovieClip {

    private var _blockTime:Number = 0;
    private var _blockLimit:Number = 20;
    private var Number_:int =0;
    private var _blockHolder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    public function MainClass() {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME ,onEveryFrame);
        this.addChild(_blockHolder)

    }


    private function onEveryFrame(ev:Event):void{
        makeBlocks();
    }


    private function makeBlocks():void{
        _blockTime++;
        if(_blockTime >= _blockLimit){
            var _block:Block = new Block();
            _block.y = Blocks_YX_Positioning()
            _block.x = Blocks_YX_Positioning()
            _blockHolder.addChild(_block);
            _blockTime = 0;
            Number_++
        }
    }

    //code so the block is staing on the stage
    private function Blocks_YX_Positioning():int{
        var _block_YX:int = Math.random()*500
        if (_block_YX < 0 ) {
             _block_YX = 50;
           }
       if (_block_YX > 450 ) {
        _block_YX = 450;
       }
       return _block_YX;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Your question isn't quite where it needs to be.  It sounds as if you're asking how to implement collision detection (basically training); these sorts of questions show a lack of research (see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you're having issues with the code that you've shared, then you'll find much more responsive community willing to help.  Keep it up; looks like you're heading in the right direction.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as implementing a 2 dimensional `Array` representing a grid. You don't need any collision detection.

This i how it goes. first you create an `Array` that represents the grid.

```
var arrayGrid = [];

// define number of elements in grid
var columns = Math.floor(500 / 70);
var rows = Math.floor(500 / 30);

// create the references: 1,2,3,4 etc.
for( var i = 0; i < columns * rows; i++ ) {
    array[i] = i;
}
```

As you can see, we are putting a number in every element of the array for every element on the imaginary grid. If the grid was 5 x 5, then it would have 25 elements.

Then you make a function like `putBrick` that puts your bricks in the stage randomly using a number from the array. I'm using 12 as the random number. At the end of the function remove the element of the array we used as a reference. At the start of the function check if the array is empty.

```
if( arrayGrid.length > 0 ){
    var someRandomNumber = 12;

    var currentCol = someRandomNumber % columns;
    var currentRow = Math.floor(someRandomNumber / columns);

    brick.x = currentCol * brick.width;
    brick.y = currentRow * brick.height;

    array.splice(someRandomNumber,1);               
} else {
    trace("we are done here!");
}
```

You will have to tweak a few things, and find the random number, but that's the core logic.

Comment: this actually worked pretty nice.I would never think of using an array to do the job.thanks very much

Comment: well i would do it but it says i dont have the needed reputation to  vote Up :( sorry